# Data only to click the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning, everyone.

I have a doubt. I have a list of div. textarea with text inside it and inside. text for a button event. Want to get only the data from the textarea div that the person clicking the button.

I would be very grateful for the help. thanks

Example code.

```
<div class="text">
 <textarea id="texts" class="texts" rows="5" cols="45" name="textarea"> </ textarea>
 <div class="bt" id="1234556">
  <div class="button"> Send </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My Dear its almost evening here. So Good Evening..... Now about your question it needs to explained more. You have not explained that where do you want to get data. On same page, other page?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have the same structure (and presuming you have more than one example on the page as the button is a class and textarea is an id, the following would work:

```
$(".button").click(function()
{

   var text = $(this).parent().prev().val();

});
```

Comment: Hello, could you help me in another question how do I get id, class = "bt"

Comment: You want the id of the element with class bt?   var theId = var text = $(this).parent().attr("id");

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    var text = $('#texts').val();

    // do something with text
    alert(text);
});
```

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/PPcxm/

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a list of `div.text` your best bet is to query based upon the structure of your DOM.

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    var $textArea = $(this).parents(".text").find(".texts");
    //Do something with $textArea.Val();
});
```

What we simply do is call `.parents()` on the current `div.button` which will allow us to get the `div.text` element.  From there you can simply find your `textarea.texts` element and get the corresponding value.

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/LMvz4/).**

Comment: Thanks, I liked this tip, I have to get other data. I will use this mode: D